# How to set a function that makes operations between columns (within a dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

## Problem

I´m making a function that describes the changes in the temporal state of a given time series. **It will say if the value of a given column is more, less, equal than the previous one**, and print the result:
It could be in the same data frame or in other different object. I´m doing
it to transform the data in order to be good for survival analysis.

### What has been done

I already made an if else ladder that looks like this: where (x) is an i column in a data drame and (y) is the column just before it (i-1). However, I am clueless about how to define the first line of the function to actually do this operation in each column of the data frame(counting from the second one), also to dont crash with the last column

```
func_name <- function (x, columns) {
if (x == NA) {
print("gone")
} else if (x < y) {
print("less")
} else if (x > y) {
print("more")
} else if (x = y) {
print("same")
} else {
print ("")
}
}
```

### What is being expected

## Ideally will be transforming something like this:

```
Id <- c(1,2,3)
Time1 <- c(3,3,4)
Time2 <- c(2,5,4)
Time3 <- c(1,5,8)
df <- data.frame(Id,Time1,Time2,Time3)
df
```

## Into something like this:

```
Id <- c(1,2,3)
Time1 <- c(3,3,4)
Time2 <- c("Less","More","Same")
Time3 <- c("Less","Same","More")
df2 <- data.frame(Id,Time1,Time2,Time3)
df2
```

Any help, highly apreciated!

## Solutions: Both @Andrew and @Cole solution works solving the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it is what you are looking for. It is not a custom function, but if can be adapted if you need one. Hope this helps!

```
# Select the columns you need. NOTE: used [-1] to remove starting time column
cols <- grep("Time", names(df), fixed = T)[-1]

# Use case_when with your conditions
df[cols] <- lapply(cols, function(i) dplyr::case_when(
  is.na(df[i]) ~ "Gone",
  df[i] > df[i-1] ~ "More",
  df[i] < df[i-1] ~ "Less",
  df[i] == df[i-1] ~ "Same"
))

df
  Id Time1 Time2 Time3
1  1     3  Less  Less
2  2     3  More  Same
3  3     4  Same  More
```

Comment: I think you need `df[cols[2:3]] <- lapply(cols[2:3]` and it will produce the OP's expected output.

Comment: @Matt good thinking, but the code should already take care of that by using `[-1]` when creating the column vector. But I updated my comment to make it more useful / clear

Comment: It threw me off that you had `Time2` as `More` in every column.

Comment: Ahh, great eye @Matt, looks like I re-ran on the altered dataframe (after I already ran the code once) before I pasted it in. Good catch!

Comment: I think @Matt is right. Plus the output doesn't match for ```Time3```

Comment: Code still works as intended but I just ran the code fresh and re-pasted the output. I should have caught that I pasted the wrong output from the get-go. Thanks for the heads up @Cole.

Comment: Cheers! It does works and it is easily escalable! Highly aprecciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the use of `mapply` with an anonymous function inside:

```
df <- data.frame(Id,Time1,Time2,Time3)

df[, 3:4] <- mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(y < x , 'Less', ifelse(y > x, 'More', 'Same'))
                    , df[, 2:3]
                    , df[, 3:4])
df
```

`mapply` will walk along each field of the datasets and apply a function. In other words, I am taking the difference between `df[, 2]` and `df[, 3]`, and then `df[, 3]` and `df[, 4]`. I could have also done something like:

```
fx_select <- function(x, y) {
ifelse(y < x, 'Less', ifelse(y > x, 'More', 'Same'))
}

df[, 3:4] <- mapply(fx_select, df[, 2:3], df[, 3:4])
```

And here's one more approach:

```
df[3:4] <- lapply(sign(df[2:3] - df[3:4]) + 2,
       function(x) c('More', 'Same', 'Less')[x]
       )
```

Comment: Cheers mate! Cheers! It does works, likewise! Highly aprecciate the help. The first second produces somes interesant results!